# How to correctly use xml.Utility.unescape?

Tags: xml, scala

After I read `xml.Utility.unescape`'s SDK document, I would think that it is the reverse action of `xml.Utility.escape`, however it does not seem to do anything at all:

```
scala> xml.Utility.escape("& <")
res0: String = &amp; &lt;

scala> val sb = new StringBuilder
sb: StringBuilder = 

scala> xml.Utility.unescape("&amp; &lt;", sb)
res1: StringBuilder = null

scala> sb.toString
res2: String = ""
```

How to correctly use `xml.Utility.unescape`?

Comment: build.sbt: `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.3.0"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked out the `unescape` documentation and I'm pretty disappointed...

> Appends unescaped string to s, amp becomes &, lt becomes < etc..
>
> **returns** null if ref was not a predefined entity.

So it seems like `unescape` is meant to append a single character to the `StringBuilder`. It thought that `"&amp; &lt;"` was "not a predefined entity" so it returned `null` for your `res1`.

Some testing in the REPL:

```
scala> unescape("amp", sb)
res9: StringBuilder = &

scala> unescape("lt", sb)
res10: StringBuilder = &<

scala> unescape(" ", sb)
res11: StringBuilder = null
```

Comment: The best part is this comment in [the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/xml/Utility.scala#L84): "For reasons unclear escape and unescape are a long ways from being logical inverses."